# FFT Algorithm leaves discontinuities in input (audio processing)

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to program an audio plugin which uses an FFT algorithm to convert audio input into frequency data, does some processing on that frequency data (I'll explain those in a second), and then converts it back into audio again. I am using the iPlug2 DSP to do the actual audio processing, and an iterative FFT algorithm I found online that I adapted to work with my program.

Some of the things I have tested so far are:

Spectral Vocoding (multiplying the amplitudes of each frequency bin by the amplitudes of a secondary audio input)

Spectral Gating (reducing all amplitudes lower than a certain threshold to zero, which gives a "lossy" sound)

Spectral Squaring (idrk what to call this, but multiplying each amplitude in the input by itself, which makes a different kind of lossy sound)

The issue that I am facing is that the reconstructed audio has a lot of clicks where each chunk of FFT meets with the next. When the audio is reconstructed, the starting value of the next chunk is much different than the last value of the previous, which makes the clicking sound.

Comment: Are you using one of the standard methods for this, e.g. overlap-add or overlap-save ?

Comment: I think so, although I don't know exactly. I just used the first method that I thought of, which was to store two buffers, one which saves the audio data as it runs and one to keep a copy of and reference when the first is full, so I can keep updating the data but still have access to it. I have an int that tracks which index of these buffers I am writing to. This converts the smaller array size into a larger power of 2 for the FFT conversion. I don't know which method that is, or if there is a more efficient alternative.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using either of the overlap methods - you might want to read up on these, as the naïve implementation where you just process sequential buffers is guaranteed to produce artefacts. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–add_method and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–save_method.

Comment: Also note that this is not really a programming question - it's more of a DSP theory question, and you'll get much better answers on https://dsp.stackexchange.com.